# PIR sensor always high with Raspberry Pi3 without breadboard

Tags: pi-3, hardware, rpi.gpio, sensor, breadboard

I have a HCSR501 PIR motion sensor, which has 3 pins (Vcc, Out, Gnd) that I've connected to 5V, GPIO 26, and Gnd respectively. Despite following all the steps in tutorials for interfacing the sensor, the input is always 'high' for me.

What confuses me is that when I do not connect it driectly to the Pi, and use a breadboard, it works (I used jumper cables with the breadboard as well as when directly connecting to the Pi). The sensor isn't extremely sensitive either,  it reads high only when i deliberately move in front of it.

Is there some resistance within the breaboard that is require when connecting directly to the Pi, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Your SR501 is too sensitive. Try AM312: https://penzu.com/p/580167ef. BTW, you don't need the Rpi to do the testing. Set Rpi aside and just use a multi-meter. Good Luck. Cheers.